# Doctrine2 Update Caused AnnotationRegistry registerLoader Error in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I'm working on a CMS based on Zend Framework 3.0 to manage a DB I with Doctrine. What is my problem when managing packages with composer? Recently, I updated all the packages to newest versions and sent it to server, nothing was changed in other files. After the update my site displayed the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in /home/platne/serwer18346/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php:117 Stack trace: #0 /home/platne/serwer18346/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Module.php(57): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(Object(Closure)) #1 /home/platne/serwer18346/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/InitTrigger.php(33): DoctrineModule\Module->init(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager)) #2 /home/platne/serwer18346/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\InitTrigger->__invoke(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 /home/platne/serwer18346/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 /home/p in /home/platne/serwer18346/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 117

Some application code if needed:
modules:

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Core',
];
```

development.local(developer mode is active):

```
'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'host' => '******',
                    'user' => '*******',
                    'password' => '******',
                    'dbname' => '*******',
                    'charset' => 'utf8'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

module.config:

```
'doctrine' => [
        'driver' => [
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [__DIR__.'/../src/Model']
            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Model' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Controller Factory:

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container,$requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $controllerInstance = null;
    switch($requestedName){
        case 'Core\Controller\IndexController': $controllerInstance = $this->_invokeIndex($container); break;
        case 'Core\Controller\PagesController': $controllerInstance = $this->_invokePages($container); break;
    }
    return $controllerInstance;
}

protected function _invokeIndex(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    return new Controller\IndexController(
        $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')
    );
}

protected function _invokePages(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    return new Controller\PagesController(
        $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')
    );
}
```

Controller Parent:

```
 protected $_entityManager;

    /**
     * AppController constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->_entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->_entityManager;
    }
```

As I said this code worked before update. After update it show me that error, what is more after uploading previous versions the error remains. I triead rewriting code but with the same effect.

Composer(without project data):

```
"require": {
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "*",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "*",
    "zendframework/zend-session": "*",
    "zendframework/zend-authentication": "*",
    "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Core\\": "module/Core/src/"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Which PHP version and which versions of Doctrine are you using? Can you post your composer.json?

Comment: I use PHP v7.0 and newest doctrine 2 orm module so I think will be 1.1.3

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This error caused by the latest version of `Doctrine\Common\Annotations` use **PHP 7.1**. That's why it use `void` as `return type`. And it is not supported on PHP 7.0.*. This is [new feature in PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.void-functions)

I use `doctrine-orm-module 1.1` in my ZF3 project using PHP 7.0. And it work well. So, just replace your `doctrine-orm-module` version to `1.1`.

```
"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "^1.1"
```

I suggest  you to define the version of dependencies you used in composer. This is purposed to make your project not broken when new version of dependencies released.

Answer (score 17):

To avoid this kind of problems, a good practice is to set the composer `config.platform` setting:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0.23"
    }
 }
```

This will tell composer to update packages but only to a version that still supports this PHP version. So typically, this version number will be the version of your production server.

Comment: If you know what you're doing and are able to, updating the php version is probably the "preferred" route. But for those that are unable to update the php version (which is probably a very high percentage), this is a much better solution.

Comment: @ffgpga08 I would add the above solution is probably a better choice when dealing with multiple server requirements. For instance, some of my projects run PHP 7.0, others 7.1. Like Node.js requirements, this is good to deal with on a per-project basis.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to use the following configuration. It works for me.

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.5.6",
        "doctrine/annotations": "1.4.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.4",
        ...
     }
```

Also very helpful when you reporting composer/package issues is the output of **composer show**. Mine looks like this:

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.4.0  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.7.0  Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.5.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.6.2  Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.4  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.8   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.3.0   Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/inflector                   v1.2.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.6  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

If you have such problems in the future, go to https://packagist.org/packages/ and search for package which causes problems.

For example **doctrine/annotations**:
https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/annotations#v1.5.0

Then look there for (*requires*: php: ^7.1) and if this package matches your PHP version.
(In your case using PHP 7.0 it doesn't match)

But https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/annotations#v1.4.0 matches your PHP version (*requires*: php: ^5.6 || ^7.0) and you can try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete composer.lock in your project, same for the "vendor" folder.

run that and enjoy ->

php composer.phar selfupdate

php composer.phar install

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your newest PHP version is running.
Sometimes when you check PHP version using `php -v` it shows the latest installed version but the older one in running.
If you installed a new version of PHP, just remove older versions:

```
apt purge php7.0 php7.0-common
```

Having same issue, after checking lots of thing, my problem solved by removing older version.