# Symfony 3 - Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned

Tags: php, apache, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an EC2 server set up with Ubuntu 16 with a LAMP installation & Symfony3.

The server is online, so there is no issue there.

I have uploaded my Symfony files to /var/www/html/project and successfully set up my parameter.yml file, set up database, and have gone through all of the installation requirements. I have run through composer.phar install, doctrine:schema:update, etc - It is all works.

I have changed my 000-default.conf to the following and have restarted apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias dev.site.com

        ServerAdmin admin@site.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/web
        DirectoryIndex app.php
        <Directory /var/www/html/project/web >
                DirectoryIndex app.php
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

> Now, when I go to view my site I get
>
> This page isn’t working
>
> dev.site.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR
>   500

So, to test and see if the 000-default.conf configuration is set up to correctly route to my Symfony installation I edited my web/app.php file and put an echo 1; die; at the header. I can then get "1" to show up on the page, so I know that the server is working and the default site is working and routing all requests to the right place.

**When I look in my error.log I get the following which I am not sure what to do or how to address this error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Return value of
>   Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader()
>   must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none
>   returned in
>   /var/www/html/project/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php:117\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/rekonnect/app/autoload.php(9):
>   Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/html/project/web/app.php(6):
>   require('/var/www/html/p...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/project/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php
>   on line 117

I have looked in the var/logs/prod.log and can find nothing in there stating why my project is throwing a 500 error.

I am not sure what to do next to get my Symfony project to show up in the browser. Any help?

Comment: You should check the content of `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`, have you looked in there?

Comment: It should be `DirectoryIndex index.php`. `app.php` should be called from there, not directly.

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista I have updated my post with the output from the error log. I am not sure what to do with that error.

Comment: Did you check folder permissions (writeable) for symfony's `cache-dir` and did clear/warmup your cache again? Further try removing the vendor folder and re-run `composer install --optimize-autoloader`? Did you deploy your `composer.lock`, too?

Answer (score 5):

You probably have a PHP version <7.1 installed on your server. Update your PHP version to resolve the issue.

The `void` return type was added in PHP 7.1. (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29793008/1832745)). Doctrine uses the `void` return type but PHP seems to look for the type in the Doctrine namespace where it can't be found.

> [..] must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void

Comment: Here is my output from php -v PHP 7.1.10-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2017 17:04:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.10-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Are you using `php-fpm`? Try restarting the service to clear the `OPcache` please.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in /var/www/html/project/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php:117\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/rekonnect/app/autoload.php(9): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/project/web/app.php(6): require('/var/www/html/p...')\n#2 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/html/project/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 117

Looking around it seems that this error is caused by the newest version of Doctrine Annotation, which uses a feature of Php 7.1. ([Doctrine2 Update Caused AnnotationRegistry registerLoader Error in Zend Framework 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337962/doctrine2-update-caused-annotationregistry-registerloader-error-in-zend-framewor)).

In order to get sure of this, I recommend to run a minimum required version analysis using a tool like [Php Compat Info](https://github.com/llaville/php-compat-info). Compare the result with the PHP version installed on your server.

If you find to have a lower version with respect to the minimum required one, you could try to upgrade PHP or to change the constraint on the PHP version in composer. For instance, if you have installed php 7.0, but the minimum required version is the 7.1, add this constraint to your composer file:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        ...
}
```

Comment: I'll add that to my composer file. I am going to try and redeploy all of my files again.

Comment: The version constraint should be `>=7.1,<7.2` to be precise as `>=7.0.0` would match `7.0.x` (definitely not working), `7.2.x` and `8.x.x` (possibly not working) ?