# Laravel error, never saw

Tags: php, laravel

```
Type error: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned
```

this is my Laravel project, it run successful in my colleague's system based on Windows, mine is Mac OS, I have no clue to resolve it, please do me a favor.

I have updated composer.

Comment: Which php version are you using? The latest version of latest of `Doctrine\Common\Annotations` uses `PHP 7.1` as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337962/doctrine2-update-caused-annotationregistry-registerloader-error-in-zend-framewor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your PHP versions on both systems. The `void` return type was introduced in PHP 7.1, so I assume you using PHP < 7.1.

Comment: yes     PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Oct  2 2017 08:58:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group

Comment: but I also have a 5.6 version in my Mac, and I have check my PATH, determine it's 7.1, do you think it's useful if I delete the 5.6 version?

Comment: The CLI is one thing. Since its running in the webserver, you have to check which PHP versions powers your Laravel instance. Create a file called `phpinfo.php` in the `public` folder of your Laravel installation and add this text: `<?php phpinfo();`  to it. Save and make it executable ... then call it via browser: example.com/phpinfo.php

You should delete old PHP version if you don`t need them anymore. If you deal with different projects who depending on older versions you should keep it.

Comment: thanks for your explaining,  I have checked my php version it's 7.0, and then I update it, I downloaded a new XAMPP,  this error has disappear,

Comment: There is no permission named `showalldata` for guard `web`. (View: /Users/hejiaxing/work/logsys/resources/views/themes/default1/agent/helpdesk/dashboard/dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: If your initial question is solved I suggest to mark it as solved and make a create a question as it looks completely different.